# ActiveX ListBox resizes after inserting rows

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a problem with maintaining ActiveX ListBoxes' sizes when I insert some entire rows.  Please see the image links.

[image: Before & After]

I already inspected the Properties panel and set 'IntegralHeight' as True and 'Locked' as True.

Any help will be hugely appreciated.  Thanks.

Properties panel fyr:
[image: Properties panel]

Comment: Is there an option to move and size with cells? This may not be available for AX Objects in Excel. I don't have this handy to check myself.

Comment: I added the properties panel for your reference.  Can type in heigh width etc indeed.  But despite locking the position (by the Locked = True property), the problem still persists.

Comment: Change `Placement` to 3 for free floating (doesn't move or size with cells), or 2 to move with cells but not size.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman you are right, thanks :) Please upvote my question you would like to!

Comment: @Rory you are right, thanks :) Please upvote my question you would like to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Holtzman was referring to the [image: Format Control] option available when you right click an object (ActiveX Control, Form Control, or Shape) in the workbook.  Form Control->Properties will allow you to choose whether an object will be resized or moved with the range of cells that it overlays.

[image: Form Control Demo]

Comment: Thanks soooo much Thomas and Scott! You guys are amazing.  Please upvote my question you would like to!